# Adding buttons next to the Close button in dialog title bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added two customized buttons on my dialog box, but they are currently just in the middle. How can i move these buttons next to the close button on the title bar, without covering or touching the close button, and also without using any`CSS`?

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSk6L/928/

Comment: Would you be open to setting css using jQuery? Like `$("button").css("float", "right");` and a small margin?

Comment: Would that cover the close button ? If not, would be ok

Comment: how can you design something without using desing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are alright using css within your jQuery then you could add a class to the minus button:

```
$('<button class="minusButton">-</button>').appendTo(titlebar).click(function() {
    $('#resultId').parents('.ui-dialog').animate({
        height: '40px',
        top: $(window).height() - 90
    }, 50);
});
```

And then set the margin

```
$(".minusButton").css("margin-left", "105px");
```

Comment: Is it also possible to make the button the same size, right now the + is little big bigger, i tried to $(".minusButton").css("margin-left", "105px", "width","20em");  but no luck

Comment: Yeah, just do `$("button").css("width", "30px");`

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use inline styling in the jquery, this gets you what you want (without floats or covering the close button - simply set a left margin to the first custom button:

`$('<button>-</button>').appendTo(titlebar).css('margin-left', '35%').click(function() {`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSk6L/929/)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to do this without at least using inline CSS, written in through jQuery.

Your best bet is just using a float and a fixed small margin on the + button so it doesn't overlap the closing button. Be aware, that any answer written here is probably going to have a problem when the user resizes the dialog window a lot, and the only way to prevent that is to give the whole dialog window a `min-width` property.

Here is what you should do:

`$('<button>+</button>').appendTo(titlebar).css({'display':'inline-block', 'float':'right', 'margin-right': '10px'}).click...`

And for the other button:

`$('<button>-</button>').appendTo(titlebar).css({'display':'inline-block', 'float':'right'}).click...`

You can see the working [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSk6L/931/)